# Multiply price into quantity for each items angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a product list in a table for each item it has a value, When the user enters the quantity in the text box I want to get value and show it in the next column. I tried the below way and it multiplies all items' values.

**Ts Code**

```
  clientProductForm = new FormGroup({
    productQty: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
  });

  proQty: number;

  quantityChange(event) {
    this.proQty = this.clientProductForm.get("productQty").value;
  }
```

**HTMl Code**

```
<tr *ngFor="let products of clientProducts">
    <td>{{ products.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ products.DistributorPrice}}</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control my-n1" formControlName="productQty" (keyup)="quantityChange($event)" /></td>
    <td>{{ products.DistributorPrice * proQty}}</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB5cE.png)

Comment: What is use of `add` button?

Comment: @navnath After the client fills in the data. I'll use it to post

Comment: You only have a single proQty - but multiple products..

Comment: @MikeOne Is there a way to achieve my target or u have a plan B?

Comment: You probably want to extend your array of products and add a quantity and subtotal key to each product.

Comment: @MikeOne Can u show me sample?

Comment: @Madhush Is this what you are looking for? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-thslvq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need a FormArray of FormControls, not a FormControl (well, you can also use an array of FormControls)

```
  clientProductForm:FormArray

  clientProductForm = new FormArray(
   this.clientProducts.map(x=>new FormControl("",Validators.required))
  });
```

Yes, you create a FormArray with so many controls as elements has your array clientProduct. We use a map instead create an empty formArray and a loop over the clientsProducts.

Use an auxiliar function

```
getQuantity(index)
{
   return this.clientProductForm.at(index) as FormControl
}
```

And iterate over the formArray.controls

```
<tr *ngFor="let control of clientProductForm.controls;let i=index">
    <!--see that you use clientProducts[i] to get the "product"-->
    <td>{{ clientProducts[i].Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ clientProducts[i].DistributorPrice}}</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control my-n1" 
       [formControl]="getQuantity(i)" /></td>
    <!--wee need "convert to number" the input, is the reason
        to use the "+" in (+clientProductForm[i].value)-->
    <td>{{ clientProducts[i].DistributorPrice *
                  (+clientProductForm.value[i])}}</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

See that in clientProductForm.value you only has an array with the quantities, e.g. [3,5.6,8,10], so I imagine that your function "submit" can be like

```
submit(){
  const data=this.clientProductForm.value.map((x,i)=>(
    { 
      name:this.clientProducts[i].name,
      quantity:x
  )
  console.log(data)
}
```

To send to your service an array of object with, e.g. the "name" and the "quantity"

Answer (score 0):

We can implement this in a very simple way,declare the `clientProducts` variable as below:

```
  clientProducts = [
    { Name: "First Product", DistributorPrice: "2500", Quantity: 0 },
    { Name: "Second Product", DistributorPrice: "1850", Quantity: 0 },
    { Name: "Class Change", DistributorPrice: "250", Quantity: 0 }
  ];

  quantityChange(event, product) {
    console.log(event, product);
  }
```

In HTML use the `Quantity` property as `ngModel` and multiply the `DistributorPrice and Quantity` in `Total`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let products of clientProducts">
  <td>{{ products.Name }}</td>
  <td>{{ products.DistributorPrice}}</td>
  <td>
    <input
      type="number"
      class="form-control my-n1"
      [(ngModel)]="products.Quantity"
      (keyup)="quantityChange($event, products)"
    />
  </td>
  <td>{{ +products.DistributorPrice * +products.Quantity}}</td>
  <td>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This may work for you. [Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-69515552-dgxxm?file=/src/app/app.component.html:352-872) to see the demo.

Thanks